# Axiom of choice and bases of vector spaces over a fixed field 

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, open-problems

Let $k$ be a field. In 1984 Andreas Blass [proved](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/bases-AC.pdf) that the axiom "for every extension $K|k$, every vector space over $K$ has a basis" implies the axiom of choice. He also raised the question

> Does the axiom "every vector space over $k$ has a basis" imply  the axiom of choice ?

What's the current status of the question ? Has there been progress ?

Comment: This has come up before:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64219

Comment: @Bruce: The two questions are clearly different.

Comment: Right -- Andreas even says toward the end of the note that the question is open for specific fields like the rationals. I hope that anyone else who votes to close this question leaves a note as to why it should be closed. 

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: @Asaf: Thanks. Perhaps you can add references and post it as answer. 

Comment: I have removed my previous comment, which contained an error, and added the relevant part as an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It has been shown for $K=\mathbb F_2$ (the field with two elements) by Keremedis ([Available here](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-08/S0002-9939-96-03305-9/S0002-9939-96-03305-9.pdf))

In [the dictionary of AC equivalences](http://consequences.emich.edu/file-source/htdocs/conseq.htm) it shows that not a lot is known on the connection between the existence of a basis over a fixed field and the axiom of choice.

Comment: As far as I can see, Keremedis shows that AC is equivalent to “every generating set of a vector space over $\mathbb F_2$ contains a basis”, which is a stronger statement than “every vector space over $\mathbb F_2$ has a basis”.

Comment: Do you mean 'weaker'?

Comment: @JanVeselý, no, because every vector space has a generating set (itself!).

Comment: @Asaf: Your link to the “dictionary of AC equivalences” is now broken — the server http://consequences.emich.edu seems to be dead/unresponsive.  Do you know if the dictionary is still live at some other URL, or can you recall more details (e.g. author, precise title) to help others locate it?

Comment: @Peter: There is a new version written by Ioanna Dimitriou: https://cgraph.inters.co/