# Do vector spaces without choice satisfy Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein?

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, vector-spaces

If $V \hookrightarrow W$ and $W \hookrightarrow V$ are injective linear maps, then is there an isomorphism $V \cong W$?

If we assume the axiom of choice, the answer is *yes*: use the fact that every linearly independent set can be extended to a basis and apply the usual [Schroeder-Bernstein theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).

If we don't assume the axiom of choice, and we work in ZF, say (or some other formalism with excluded middle), then vector spaces don't necessarily have bases (in fact, [Blass showed](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Eablass/bases-AC.pdf) that there *must* be a vector space without a basis over some field), so we can't use the same proof strategy. Nevertheless, there's room for optimism, since Schroeder-Bernstein still holds for *sets* in ZF. So one might hope that it also holds for vector spaces in ZF.

**Question:** Work in ZF (or some other formalism with excluded middle but without choice). If $V \hookrightarrow W$ and $W \hookrightarrow V$ are injective linear maps of vector spaces over a field $k$, then is there an isomorphism $V \cong W$?

**Variation 1:** What if we assume that $k$ is finite, or even that $k = \mathbb F_p$ for a prime $p$?

**Variation 2:** What if we assume that $V$ is a direct summand of $W$ and vice versa?

The following consequence of [Bumby's theorem](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01220018) appears to be constructive: If $k$ is a ring and every $k$-module is injective, then $k$-modules satisfy Schroeder-Bernstein. But the condition "every module over a field is injective" sounds pretty choice-ey to me. I suppose it's worth noting, though:

**Variation 3:** Does "Every vector space over any field is injective" imply choice? How about "Every vector space over $\mathbb F_p$ is injective"?

Comment: This question was discussed in the comments of this Secret Blogging Seminar post from 2007: https://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2007/10/30/theme-and-variations-schroeder-bernstein/

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Without the axiom of choice, it is possible that there is a vector space $U\neq 0$ over a field $k$ with no nonzero linear functionals.

Let $V$ be the direct sum of countably many copies of $U$, and $W=V\oplus k$.

Then each of $V$ and $W$ embeds in the other, but they are not isomorphic, since $V$ doesn’t have any nonzero linear functionals, but $W$ does.

I don't think there's any restriction on the field $k$, so this answers Variation 1 as well.

Comment: Thanks! Where can I read about such vector spaces $U$? And when you say "it is possible", do you mean "If every vector space admits a linear functional, then choice holds", or just that "there are models of ZF where not every vector space admits a linear functional"? I think this touches on Variation 3 as well, since if $U$ doesn't admit any linear functionals, then it is certainly not injective!

Comment: @Tim: to be explicit, I think something along the lines of $\prod k / \oplus k$ (countable product and sum) already may not admit nonzero linear functionals in, say, a model of ZF with no non-principal ultrafilters.

Comment: @TimCampion I meant "there are models ..." Take a look at [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49388), where people more expert than me explain why every nonzero vector space having a linear functional doesn't imply choice.

Comment: Sounds like something someone gave a short talk about in Bristol just before lockdown... :-)

Comment: @Jeremy: that thread's a lovely find and resolved a question I'd been wondering about on math.SE! To pull an example out of it explicitly: there's a model of ZF in which $\mathbb{R}$ considered as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space has no nonzero linear functionals, and in fact in which every homomorphism $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous (which implies this).

Comment: So this answer works because for $U$ non-zero vector space, existence of non-zero linear $f: U \rightarrow K$ needs choice, but $f: K \rightarrow U$ does not. I have to admit this confused me for a second, because it turns out I didn't understand what AC actually is.

Comment: I wonder how all of this relates to the way that $\mathbb R$ behaves as a condensed abelian group...

Answer (score 30):

There are models of ZF+DC in which every subset of every Polish space has the property of Baire (I can try to add references later, I think to Solovay and Shelah, but these are pretty well known).  This implies that every linear map between Banach spaces is continuous.

So we can then take $\ell^\infty$ and $\ell^1$.  It is very easy to construct (continuous) linear injections either way: the identity map from $\ell^1$ into $\ell^\infty$, and to go the other way, map $x_n$ to $2^{-n} x_n$.

But if there were a linear isomorphism between them, it would be a homeomorphism, and this is impossible because $\ell^1$ is separable and $\ell^\infty$ isn't.

(As a tie-in to Jeremy's answer, in this model $\ell^1$ is reflexive, and $\ell^\infty / c_0$ is a Banach space with no nonzero linear functionals.)

Comment: Did you mean "every subset of a Polish space has the property of Baire"?

Comment: @tomasz: I did, thanks.  Fixed.